# .git folder that has only link to repository, but no files embedded

Tags: git, version-control

Short version of the question would be:

**What do I put to .git folder for the developer to be able to pull the newest version from the server, but not have the older one files embedded into .git?**

Reason why I need that:

I have my application's core **and** other solutions that use the core.

I want to use separate GIT repository for the core and separate repository for every solution that uses core.

*For examples sake, let us call core application Simple and new project Super*

What I have so far is this structure:

```
Simple
Super.Config
Super.Web
```

A few comments:

```
Simple
----Here are core files
Super.Config
----Here are configuration files
Super.Web
----Here is the web project that uses core
```

Everything works just fine and I have all core files in a separate repository and Super repository looks like this:

```
Super.Config
Super.Web
```

What I want to do is add the ***Simple*** folder to ***Super*** repository with **.git** folder in there wich has only core repository url and not the files. Just for the **Super** project developer to be able to pull the latest core version from repository.

Therefore the structure that I want would be like this:

```
Simple
----.git
Super.Config
Super.Web
```

And when developer gets this structure, he/she just pulls files in ***Simple*** directory and gets the newest version of the core.

Comment: Are you asking about [submodules](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want, I think you are talking about git submodules.

Have a look here as it's explained much better than I can!

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: I knew about them, but never used them... Thanks, I'll check that out! :)